# SalesForce workflow based on a formula field

Tags: community, workflow

I have a formula field which is a check box that automatically is ticked/not ticked depending on the formula criteria. This formula field works perfectly for me.

Although i have various workflows which i am trying to set-up which are based upon the result of this formula field. I have tried various aspects for getting this to work but cannot seem to fix this, has anyone any suggestions?

Currently my workflow criteria is:

```
ISPICKVAL(Active_Client_c,"Yes") && Formula_Field_c <> null
```

I have looked for previous questions but none of the solutions seem to work for me as there is no manual interaction from anyone to change the Formula_Field as its automatic. The current method only works when someone has edited/modified the record in question but I need this to work automatically even if a record has not been edited. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you write in the comments, your formula field looks like this:

```
(Client_Review_Due_Date__c < TODAY()) && (!Review_Submitted__c)
```

And you want the workflow to fire when the formula field evaluates to true *1. However, as you notice, the workflow does not trigger when the formula field changes.

That is because the formula field does not actually 'change' or have a stored value: it is calculated on the fly and only if you actively ask for it, e.g. when you view the page or query for it in SOQL.

So my suggestion would be not to use the formula field at all. If you want the workflow to fire when the Client_Review_Due_Date__c < TODAY(), then it is better to rewrite the workflow as

```
ISPICKVAL(Active_Client_c,"Yes") && !Review_Submitted__c
```

And then plan time-dependent actions that will fire 7 days after Client_Review_Due_Date__c, 10 days after Client_Review_Due_Date__c etc.

That is safe, because if the workflow criteria won't match, the planned actions will be removed from the queue and the emails will not be sent.

*1: I assume you mean to say == True instead of <> null...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would this mean to create a field and have the field auto update with something to fire the other workflows. Would could this be?

Comment: You usually don't need an additional field, as you can e.g. do a DML update without changing anything (Trigger) or do a field update on the Name field and fill it with the current Name (Workflow).

Comment: The takeaway is that you can only work from the 'source' of the change, i.e. the record that is actually changing, and then actively bubbling up from there. A formula field doesn't work for triggering workflow criteria because it is only calculated 'on request' (e.g. when it is shown on a page or queried via SOQL) and doesn't trigger anything by itself.

Comment: Thank you Willem for your help, so just to confirm as i would be using a workflow and not an Apex Trigger. I would create a field update on a field such a the name field and set this to fill with the current name each day? Would this fix my problem. Does the field that is being updated have to be a certain field type and i would need to set it to re-evaluate workflows after change, is that correct?

Comment: Sorry also when the field is set to update, do i need then to have a work to tell the field when to update?

Comment: Don't just fill the name each day, but actually look at when the change happens and where it happens. You can see that from the formula field, right? What is in your formula field? What other records does it use to calculate its value?

Comment: The formula field is set as "(Client_Review_Due_Date__c < TODAY()) && (!Review_Submitted__c)"  The Review_Submitted__c is a checkbox

Comment: Ah so, there is no 'other' record where something changes, but the changes lie in the fact that the data of TODAY() changes. Then your solution of changing the name every day might work. Does the workflow trigger when you edit the record manually?

Comment: They work when i manually tick the box (Review_Submitted) save, then open and untick the box and save, but do not work when i simply make anyother change on the record save and edit.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, because probably you have the workflow set to 'created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria', so it will only trigger when it first *did not* meet criteria and subsequently *did* meet criteria. If you want it to always trigger, set it to 'created, and every time it's edited'

Comment: It wont let me change that as it says there are time dependant workflow actions.

Comment: Basically the workflow i want to trigger has various email alerts for 7 days after, 10 days after, 13 days after due date etc.

Comment: And you really want to send out those emails on *every* change of the record? Usually the 'created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria' is good enough. Anyway, that's not even relevant here. Just make sure that you trigger e.g. a name change every day, and it will evaluate the workflows and if (Client_Review_Due_Date__c < TODAY()) && (!Review_Submitted__c) the formula field will evaluate to true and the workflow will fire. That should work.

Comment: Thanks William, the emails would be basically send out when they are overdue, this would be the formulae field so we want this to happen as sometimes the record may not have been edited for it to fire. Sorry can i ask you to explain your last guidance. I need to create a workflow that updates any field in the record and this needs to happen each day? How would this be best set-up to evaluate the workflows?

Comment: See my updated answer. All in all you shouldn't use the formula field at all. I hope that helps!

Comment: Thans Willem, i have seen your suggestion in the to answer. I edited the workflow to exclude the formula field but it does not seem to work. Is this because we no longer are calculating the Client_Review_Due_Date__c < TODAY() to see if it is less than today?

Comment: Sorry would this only work for new records is that why I'm not seeing it working? Would this basically be running a workflow from when a record is created and has the emails queued up but removes them if and when a review is submitted. I am understanding this correctly.

Comment: Hey Chris, yes you understand that correctly! You can check the queued actions if you go to Monitor -> Time Based Workflow -> Search and see them disappear when the review is submitted.

Comment: Thank you for your help above. I have now edited the workflows criteria as per your advice which will work for new clients that have been added. What is the easiest way for me to rigger these now for clients that already exist, what would i have to edit in their record for those workflows to trigger easily if you know what i mean. Also sorry if the emails are all scheduled and pushed to the queue when a record is created, if a client owner or date changes will this update the emails in the queue with the new dates and new owner to email etc?

Comment: Just do any edit/update on existing records, and the workflow will trigger (that is, if you have the evaluation criteria set to 'created, and edited to subsequently meet the criteria'. Can do this with Apex if you like. The latter question might be good to ask a new question on Salesforce Stackexchange, so others can benefit from the answer!

Comment: Thank you, i tried to make any edit to the record but it did not work so i had to manually tick and untick the submitted box to trigger to the emails for some reason.